# add mysql columns on the fly

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to add mysql columns on the fly when I try to insert a row?

For example, table contains columns A, B, C and I want to insert into the table a row that contains A, C, D, and F?

Is there a way to actually add the D and F columns instead of resulting in an error?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why would you need to add columns?

Comment: please see my comment to Ofir Baruch below

Comment: Why not use a key-value relationship for the table then? That is, your table is three total columns: userid, key, value. Primary key being (userid,key)

Comment: you're a genius! You've just made my day. the only little problem would be with type of values (i.e. one of the columns was supposed to be a timestamp, and a few of them are text instead of varchar, but i really don't care about efficiency of the table, since its use will be minimal anyway

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: Consider closing your question or answering yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you GlaciesofPacis and Adev

You made me think differently about the question that I asked, and it looks like your solution is a lot more elegant than what I was initially thinking about.

Instead of having a table with very few rows and over 100 columns, I will use the ID, Key, Value model.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Alter` and `ADD` in order to add new columns to your table.

For instance;

```
ALTER TABLE contacts ADD email VARCHAR(60);
```

Will add a new column named `email` which its type if `Varchar` , to the `contacts` table.

Of course that before you insert the row , you must check which columns to add,
add them and just then insert the new row.

Comment: well, that's exactly the issue, if I KNEW which fields I will have the database, there'd be no reason to add the fields on the fly. I will simply be dumping various variables into the database with the name of the variable being the name of the column, and I would like to be able to not bother with figuring out which column already exists...

Comment: I am not following you... when you get the new values , you check which fields you want to add (using `if` for instance). Then , you add those fields and insert value.
Rewrite your question in a proper way so I could understand.
`And add an example`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ALTER TABLE and give it any query you need for example

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
ADD COLUMN_NAME (ATTRIBUTE)
```

hope this helps you